# How to config the kafka consumer to listen messages only in a given time range

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want my kafka consumer to listen to kafka server only from 8AM to 8PM. It should not listen to requests that comes out of that time range. Is this configuration possible. If so how to do that.

I have developed the kafka consumer in java.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka does not care about your consumers, so there is no config for that.
Either make your consumer stop consuming outside your time frame entirely (think Cron-Job, or just do not poll if outside frame) or consume but do not process, which would advance the offset.
The fist option would "continue" the work on 8AM, the second would ignore everything outside your timeframe.
If you own the consumer it should be easy to implement.